Wave equation and mixed derivatives
Is it possible to explain, in a reasonably simple way, why mixed partial derivatives do not appear in the two- and three-dimensional wave equation?

If we consider the wave equation
$$
c^2\nabla^2 F = {\partial^2 F\over \partial t^2} 
$$
The Laplacian operator in l.h.s. has many possible forms, depending on the coordinate system. For generalized coordinates $q_j$, it could be written as
$$
c^2 g^{jk}\left ( {\partial^2 F\over \partial q_j \partial q_k} - \Gamma^l_{jk} {\partial F\over \partial q_l} \right ) = {\partial^2F\over \partial t^2}.
$$
Where $g^{jk}$ is the inverse metric tensor and $\Gamma^l_{jk}$ is the connection pseudo-tensor. It happens that in Cartesian or spherical or cylindrical coordinates, the metric tensor is diagonal, because the coordinates are independent, so there is no mixed partial derivatives.

Physically, the geometry of space is related to how the wave fronts and geodesics would be. In Cartesian coordinates, we have the simple solution of plane waves
$$
F(\mathbf r, t) = e^{i(\mathbf k\cdot \mathbf r - \omega t)}
$$
With $\omega = ck$. In more general geometries, we could search solutions of the form
$$
F(\mathbf r,t) = e^{i(\mathcal L(\mathbf r)-\omega t)}
$$
Where by direct substitution, we would get an equation for $\mathcal L(\mathbf r)$, that is called the eikonal. The wave fronts are defined as surfaces of equal phase in each time, i.e.
$$
\mathcal L(\mathbf r)  = Cte.
$$

Thank you, Ruffolo. I can almost understand the first part of your answer, as it is above my math skills. However, I can see the association with your clarification "It happens that in Cartesian or spherical or cylindrical coordinates, the metric tensor is diagonal, because the coordinates are independent, so there is no mixed partial derivatives."
